# SQL 2005 - SSL Security error at connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, ssl-certificate

A client of mine has an application that is being migrated from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005. After the DB migration, the following error is occurring when the application tries to execute a SQL query.

xSomeClassTools: 3/30/2010 9:27:42 AM-ErrorMessage:SSL Security error.- StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Boolean& isInTransaction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionPoolManager.GetPooledConnection(SqlConnectionString options, Boolean& isInTransaction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at xSomeApplication.Tools.xSomeClassTool.writeRecord(String fieldChanged, String newValue, String dn) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xSomeApplication\components\xSomeClassTool.cs:line XXX

Beyond the account used by the application, I don't have access to the SQL server. According to the DBA's they have a default installation of SQL 2005, with the database migrated from SQL 2000. Has anyone seen this error before and know how to resolve it?

Comment: can you run this query on an external tool with the same credentials ?

Comment: From the error message, it is failing to connect. I have verified that I can connect, and run the proc the application was trying to run on from my machine.

Comment: Adding Trusted_Connection=False and Network Library=DBMSSOCN to the connection string did not resolve the issue. Also checked the SQL Client Config and they didn't check the box to require encrypted connections.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898

Perhaps they need to install a cert?

Comment: Using the installation process for SQL 2000 we verified that the old server did not require a cert. I also asked them to look for self signed certificates. The SQL 2000 server did not have any, but the SQL 2005 server did have a self signed root certificate. I tried to get them to temporarily remove it, but they were not willing to.